# Convert Database Data to utf8 - What is the correct way?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have `MYSQL` database collation set to `latin1_swedish_ci` but my site uses encoding `windows-1256`. This means the data inside tables is encoded with `windows-1256`.

What is the correct way to convert my database tables/fields and data to `utf-8` using `iconv` or any other library?

Comment: Can you not do it using MySQL?

Comment: Export DB, reimport using different encoding on the tables, unless your data-set is massive.

Comment: How to do using MYSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to verify that the data in the table(s) is really latin1.  Could you do `SELECT HEX(col), col ...` to see what it looks like.

Depending on whether it is latin1 encoding or utf8 encoding (or something else) will determine what steps to perform.  (If you do these steps without knowing, you could make things worse.)

These references give you the next steps:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html and/or
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll